# How to call remove_column on SALV table?

Tags: abap

I want to execute the method `remove_column` on an instance of `cl_salv_column_table` but because of its visibility level, I am not able to do so.

---

**Plan:**

I already tried inheriting from `cl_salv_columns_list` and then perform the call inside the `remove`-method:

```
CLASS lcl_columns_list DEFINITION INHERITING FROM CL_SALV_COLUMNS_LIST.
    PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:
        remove IMPORTING iw_colname TYPE string.
ENDCLASS.
```

But apparently my casting knowledge got rusty as I'm not able to figure out an appropriate solution.

This is my current hierarchy - the red arrows show the way I would have to take:

[image]

My approach looks like this:

```
DATA lo_column_list TYPE REF TO lcl_columns_list.
lo_column_list ?= CAST cl_salv_columns_list( lo_columns ).
```

But it fails with:

> ```
> CX_SY_MOVE_CAST_ERROR
> Source type: \CLASS=CL_SALV_COLUMNS_TABLE
> Target type: "\PROGRAM=XXX\CLASS=LCL_COLUMNS_LIST"
> ```

---

**Background:**

My task is to select *all* columns of 3 tables (which would be done like `SELECT t1~*, t2~*, t3~* ...`) as long as their names don't conflict (e.g. field `MANDT` should only be displayed once). This would require defining a very big structure and kick the size of the selection list to a maximum.

To avoid this, I wanted to make use of the type generated by my inline-declaration. Hiding the individual columns via `set_visible( abap_false )` would still display them in the layout manager - which looks really ugly.

Is there any other way to accomplish my target?

Comment: Why do you want to call the method in the first place?

Comment: @vwegert I edited my question

Comment: Also... If a method was implemented - I should be able to use it somehow

Answer (score 1):

Use `set_technical( abap_true )` to hide the columns entirely. As for your approach - sorry, inheritance does not work that way - in no statically typed object oriented language that I know. You can't 'recast' an instantiated object to a different class. You would need to modify the framework extensively to support that.

Comment: Thank you, for this answer! But a main part of this question also was invoking `remove_column` - regardless of my actual target. It would be very nice if this could be solved somehow too

Comment: If a method is not marked as public, there's usually a reason for that. I believe your assumption "if it's there, I must be able to call it" is flawed - there are lots of internal methods that are not fully implemented, were never completed, are untested an unsupported or require special preparations. The concept of visibility was invented for a reason...